Compose TextField lose focus when newline on Samsung Note 10 Lite
Surface {
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(32.dp)) {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    TextField(value = state,
        onValueChange = { state = it },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
    )
}}

Those code are my TextField and it lose focus when I click the newline button at soft keyboard. This situation only occurs on Samsung Note 10 Lite, but other devices are normal.

Have you tried adding a focusRequester with modifier.focusRequester {...}?
